# Is there a function in R or Python that can calculate the share % of a multi-select Tableau filter individually?

Tags: python, r, tableau-api

Looking to calculate the share % of multiple values selected in a filter individually without aggregating them together.

This is going to be utilized in Tableau where the user opens the dashboard and selects items in a filter (n).  The (n) items each need their share % calculated and then added together in a later step.

Here is what I have so far:

```
State Sales = SUM({FIXED [State],[Sub-Category] : SUM([Sales])})

State Total Sales = SUM({FIXED [Sub-Category] : SUM([Sales])})

Share % = State Sales / State Total Sales
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a fixed level of detail on the percent values in Tableau and it worked.  Thanks for helping out!  I didn't explain very well what I was trying to do.  I was having a hard time trying to explain exactly what I needed help with.  Thanks again!!

Here is the formula that finally worked:

```
Share Sum = SUM({FIXED [State], [Sub-Category] : [Share %]}) / COUNTD([Sub-Category])
```

Answer (score 0):

No, weighted averages always have a weighing attribute set by the user.  For instance, the quantity weighted stock sale price for a week might be the sum of ( each sale price by the number of shares sold ) / total shares sold.  So, 500 shares at $1 and 100 shares at $1.10 is $610/600 = $1.016667 quantity-weighted average price.

Comment: Hi David.  The weights need to be calculated, but are not given. Is that the same thing as you are mentioning above?  The weights are determined by the share % (sum/total(sum)).

Comment: Unweighted average is by share alone, but weighting is dragging in an orthogonal parameter to adjust the impact of the thing being averaged, like price by volume in my example.  Perhaps you are thinking frequency?  I can't see that providing better information, the purpose of weighting.

Can you show us what you got?

Comment: Hi David.. I edited my question to be more relevant to what I was actually trying to do.  Sorry for the confusion on my part.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your response. What I was trying to do was have Tableau let the user select multiple items in a filter, and then have Tableau calculate the Share % for those multiple items individually along another dimension. Then combine those values together and divide by the number of items selected in the filter. I figured out how to do it by using this formula: Share Sum = SUM({FIXED [State], [Sub-Category] : [Share %]}) / COUNTD([Sub-Category])